# Multidimensional array returning 'undefined' value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in javascript as the code below:

```
var solidos = [];
solidos[0] = [];
solidos[0].push({
    nome: 'Octaedro regular',
    dimensoes: 'Aresta = 100mm',
    material: 'Placa de alumínio',
    tempo: '2 horas',
    maquinario: 'Dobradeira e Morsa',
    imagem: 'octaedro.gif'
});
```

When I give a alert in some element of the array, it returns me 'undefined'. 
Why?

---

```
alert(solidos[0].nome);
```

Results: undefined

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a `nested array`.

You have to try like,

```
alert(solidos[0][0].nome);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
alert(solidos[0].nome);
```

To:

```
alert(solidos[0][0].nome);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a 2-dimensional array, as you indicate. The value at index `0` is an array, not an object. You need to access the key of the second array:

```
alert(solidos[0][0].nome);
```

Please see this [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WA6MJ/).

Answer (score 0):

See my working jsFiddle demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PNgf/1/)

```
var solidos = [];
    solidos[0] = [];
    solidos[0].push({
    nome: 'Octaedro regular',
    dimensoes: 'Aresta = 100mm',
    material: 'Placa de alumínio',
    tempo: '2 horas',
    maquinario: 'Dobradeira e Morsa',
    imagem: 'octaedro.gif'
});

console.log(solidos[0][0]);
alert(solidos[0][0].nome);
```

In the firebug console, you can see that logging solidos[0] returns an array
and logging solidos[0][0] returns the first element in that array.